# Is this enough to convince clients to pay for Hotjar?

Tags: client, user-tracking

In our agency we'd like to convince our clients to let us install a visitor-tracking tool ([Hotjar](https://www.hotjar.com/)) on the e-commerce shops that we create for them.
It would be beneficial for both sides, we would see if our designs work well or cause trouble with users and the client would have user-insights for his own page and develop own strategies based on that.

Now the thing is that we wouldn't want to be the ones paying the fee for it for every client, so the better way is of course to let the clients pay for it, while we manage it. What would be the best way of approaching this topic and what arguments to use (and in what priority)?

So far I've came up with this:

1. **Heatmaps**

   - Incredibly useful tool to see a summary/average of user behavior on your site
   - Do users see important elements?
   - Which types of photography attracts the most attention (and you should therefore continue to use)?
2. **User Recordings**

   - Great in combination with heatmaps
     -> If anything seems off on heatmaps, watching a few recordings of user behavior can really help understand it
   - After watching only 10-15 of such recordings, you already have a much deeper insights of what your users do on your site or how their shopping behavior
3. **Funnels**

   - See where users drop off the most and single out the problematic pages
     -> Makes it easy to fix funnels
4. **Price & Ease of Use**

   - Only $30/month (or $90 for more) for such deep insights is a bargain
   - Result data is not cryptic and needs to be deeply analyzed, just a few quick looks are enough to understand the main theme in the behavior
5. **Extra** (Not that important)

   - Questionnaires and polls to gather direct feedback or interact with customers

Is this the right direction or does it sound too simplistic?
**One important thing** to note is that our clients can be pretty cheap sometimes and need convincing even for $30 a month (even though they make enough to ignore such an amount).

---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been both the designer and the client in situations like this. It's best to not let your clients get involved in the selection of the tools you use to do your job. If you feel strongly about using Hotjar to accomplish what you need for this client, pay the $30 and roll it into the total price of the project. It's the cost of getting the website that they want; they're paying for your expertise.

Comment: The thing is that it's a monthly fee, whereas they're paying a fixed amount for their site to be built by us. I suppose we can include the fee one way or another; but we review the pricing with them in detail, that is why I wanted to make sure my arguments are on point before presenting them the Hotjar idea.

Comment: It's not necessarily about this tool specifically, just about convincing them to use a visitor tracking tool so we can gather useful data to review our designs.

Comment: You might find that the client is happy to pay for the tracking tool, but will (reasonably) want access to it, will be watching user recordings themselves, and will be interpreting them/ directing you without the professional UX background that you have. You might have a savvy client who would be good at this, but most business owners think they know more than they know about UX research. I'd personally keep them out of Hotjar and just add the cost to your fixed amount.

Answer (score -2):

An alternative solution is to use a cheaper, self-hosted alternative to Hotjar and then you can even charge your clients for the extra insights and make some profit out of it. By self-hosting you would save a lot compared to the Hotjar plans.